# I got pooped on by a bird (maybe a pigeon) during puja in the temple. Is it good or bad?

Tags: animals, puja, meaning, omens

I got pooped on by a bird (maybe a pigeon) during puja in the temple.

Is it a good omen or a bad omen, as per the scriptures?

Comment: Well.... If a bird sits on one's head it's considered a bad omen for the person's upcoming death. Not sure, what does getting pooped mean as per scriptures. But yeah, in several places that's considered a good omen for upcoming auspiciousness in one's life.